# Android Toggle Buttons Off Colors

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

I'm working with a ToggleButton in my Android app and it is functioning fine.  The one issue I'm having is that I'd like to color of the button to be red in it's off state.  Currently it's green in it's On state, so I'd like the off color to keep everything consistent and to give users a visual cue.

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find any information on how to do this.  I thought there would be a property or something I could set, but scanning through the button's documentation hasn't turned up anything.  Is there a way to do this?  If not, is there a better option someone could recommend?  The ToggleButton has 95% of what I need, if I can get the Off color working, I'll have everything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is called a `StateListDrawable`.  The developer doc is available [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).  There are plenty of examples on the internet on how to implement these.  Google works great for this.

The downside of this, is it IMHO is quite a bit of work just to change the look of your widget.  Whether or not the "return on investment" is worth it is totally up to you.